# How do you determine one's complement and two's complement in Python?

Tags: python, twos-complement, ones-complement

Here's what I have so far:

decimalEquivalent is variable that represents an integer.

```
#One's complement of the binary string is shown
onesComplement = bin(~decimalEquivalent)
print(f'The negative no (-{decimalEquivalent}) using 1\'s Complement: {onesComplement}')

#Two's complement of the binary string is shown
twosComplement = onesComplement + bin(1)
print(f'The negative no (-{decimalEquivalent}) using 2\'s Complement: {twosComplement}')
```

Could you help me figure out what I am doing wrong?

I was trying to determine one's complement and two's complement for an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bin` returns a string. You need to do all of your arithmetic *before* calling `bin`, or you'll just be concatenating strings. Consider

```
#One's complement of the binary string is shown
onesComplement = ~decimalEquivalent
print(f'The negative no (-{decimalEquivalent}) using 1\'s Complement: {bin(onesComplement)}')

#Two's complement of the binary string is shown
twosComplement = onesComplement + 1
print(f'The negative no (-{decimalEquivalent}) using 2\'s Complement: {bin(twosComplement)}')
```